# Enviar e-mail UTF-8 através do ASP com CDONT

Tags: codificação-de-caracteres, asp

Estou tentando enviar um formulário para um e-mail usando o CDONT, porém o charset está chegando incorreto e não está mostrando os caracteres com acentuação de forma correta.

```
<%
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
mail_to = "meu@email.com"

Dim f, emsg, mail_to, r, o, c, other
emsg =  "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=""pt-br""><head><meta charset=""UTF-8"" /></head><body>" & _
        "<strong>Solicitante: " & Request("txtSol") & vbCrLF & _
        "Data da solicitação:</strong> " & Request("txDatatSol") & vbCrLF  & _
        "Setor: " & Request("cboSetor") & vbCrLF & _
        "Descrição do produto/serviço: "  & vbCrLF & Request("txtProdServ") & vbCrLF & _
        "Justificativa da solicitação: "  & vbCrLF & Request("txtJust") & vbCrLF & _
        "Valor médio: " & Request("txValor") & vbCrLF & _
        "Prazo limite: " & Request("txDatatLim") & vbCrLF & _
        "Especificações técnicas do produto/serviço e requisitos da qualidade exigidos: "  & vbCrLF & Request("txtEspcTec") & vbCrLF & _
        "Produto Crítico? " & Request("rdoCritico") & vbCrLF & _
        "Possíveis fornecedores: " & vbCrLF & Request("txtFornc")  & vbCrLF & _
        "Fornecedor exclusivo? " & Request("rdoExclusivo") & vbCrLF & _
        "Você confirma o envio do parecer técnico? " & Request("rdoParecer") & _
        "</body> </html>"

For Each f In Request.Form
    If mid(f,1,1)<>"S"  = True Then
        emsg = emsg & f & " = " & Trim(Request.Form(f))
    End If
Next

Set objNewMail = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail")
    objNewMail.From = Request("txtSol")
    objNewMail.Subject = "Solicitação de compra"
    objNewMail.To = mail_to
    objNewMail.BodyFormat=0
    objNewMail.MailFormat=0
    objNewMail.Body = emsg 
    objNewMail.Send
    Set objNewMail = Nothing

response.redirect "home.asp?status=enviado"

%>
```

Comment: O arquivo fonte está com a codificação em UTF-8? Você pode verificar abrindo ele no Notepad++ e indo em Formatar. Inclusive, pode converter para UTF-8. Como seu e-mail está obtendo dados de outra página, verifique se lá também está em UTF-8. E envie o Formulário usando `POST`.

Comment: Sim, os arquivos estão em UTF-8. Já testei tanto através do `POST` quanto `GET`.

Answer (score 3):

Para trabalhar com UTF-8 não basta `Response.CodePage` e o `Response.Charset`, é necessário salvar ambos documentos em [*UTF-8 sem BOM*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Official_name_and_variants), tanto o arquivo do envio quanto o arquivo que contem o formulário.

Dois softwares que podem ser usados para salvar o documento com a codificação necessária, são os notepad++ ou o SublimeText:

Usando notepad++:

[image: utf8 sem boom notepad++]

Usando Sublime Text:

[image: utf8 sublime sublimetext]

Se você tem certeza que ambos arquivos estão salvos assim, então é necessário aplicar `Response.CodePage` e `Response.Charset` em ambos documentos.

Se já o fez todos estes procedimentos e o envio do e-mail continua com problemas nos caracteres, então será necessário usar uma destas propriedades, como citou o colega na outra resposta:

```
objNewMail.BodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"
```

ou

```
objNewMail.HTMLBodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"
```

Um detalhe, eu não tenho muito conhecimento de Asp clássico, mas acredito que o `mail_to = "meu@email.com"` deveria ir depois de `Dim`:

```
Dim f, emsg, mail_to, r, o, c, other

mail_to = "meu@email.com"
emsg =  "<!DOCTYPE html>...
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que possa enviar emails com a codificação correcta em UTF-8, utilize:

```
bjCDOMailer.TextBodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"
```

Para que o encoding funcione correctamente:

```
objCDOMailer.BodyPart.Charset = "utf-8" 
objCDOMailer.HTMLBodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"
```

Comment: Assim funciona somente com `CDO.Message`.